# Calculate $\cos(\pi/20)$ with error less then $10^{-5}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I used MacLaurin series up to n=4, $\lvert R_{4}(x) \rvert < 10^{-5}$ and after I calculated the series with $\frac \pi {20} $ I got something like 0.9876.. and then I checked on the calculator to see if everything is ok and what I got is $\cos(\frac {\pi}{20}) = 0.999996..$ so the difference between what I got  and the "real" value is $0.999996-0.9876$ and this is greater then $10^{-5}$. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess your calculator is in degrees mode. You have to switch to radians.

Comment: yep ^^ haha It was on degrees mode, after switching to radians I got the right results. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28pi%2F20%29

The calculator is probably the problem